# Why doesn't this phase shift oscillator work?

Tags: oscillator, simulation, design

[image]

I have to achieve 100 MHz oscillation frequency. To startup the oscillation,  V2 is modeled as a step voltage source with 10V final value. But I am not getting any oscillation when I try to simulate this on a simulation software.
What is the problem in this design. Please, I really need help with this.

Comment: For 100 MHz try 10pf and compute z(f)

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75, did you mean I should replace 1pF capacitor with 10pF? I cannot do that, because i have to design for 1pF and 100MHz. These are the only requirements.

Comment: No C5 time constant is almost 1 second, when things dont work , checking the voltages for each node will tell you whats wrong.

Comment: Also the source impedance to load attenuation must be lower  than gain for unity gain at 180deg

Answer (score 1):

Break the loop, insert a signal (Vin) as shown below and plot the AC response of the circuit from 10 MHz to 1 GHz and see what happens: -

[image]

I suspect that there will not be enough gain when the phase response is 0 degrees OR, try running the simulation for a longer time-period because sometimes, oscillators need some time to begin noticeably oscillating i.e. they do not start instantly. If you have the option, run the elongated transient response **not from** the estimated operating point but right from t = 0 i.e. there should be some provision in your tool to **stop** the tool calculating the DC bias points and "unhelpfully" beginning the transient point when those transients have settled down. On MC12 (my tool) it is shown here: -

[image]

I never run oscillators with that option ticked even though my tool annoyingly defaults to it. Maybe it's the same in your sim.

Comment: Then wait a second for the bias to normalise...;)

Comment: It would be faster to fix it in Falstad, but my dog wants to take me for a walk/run

Answer (score 0):

I've never had much success with that high pass configuration of the RC phase shift network in a phase shift oscillator. You could try the low pass configuration as below in which the drain resistor (amplifier's output resistance) forms the first R in the phase shift network.

[image: Phase shift oscillator]

Note how the amplifier saturates. This reduces the loop gain to 1 once the oscillator is running.

The simulator I've used won't simulate up to the sort of frequencies you're after but you could try with your simulator and reduce the C values in the phase shift network.